# Vim: enable syntax highlight of different type inside a syntax region?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I use latex to typeset lots of code using the `minted` package. Mainly the layout of my Latex source looks like this:

```
... text ...
\begin{cppcode}
class GenericClass{
    public:
        int publicMember;
    private:
        int privateMember;
}
\end{cppcode}
... text ...
```

Is there anyway to tell Vim to highlight the code inside the `\begin{cppcode}` `\end{cppcode`} as if it `C++` code?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem when using awk and perl code inside bash scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can - please see [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip857) for details.

Comment: can't get this to work.. It never recognizes my `end` statement, leaving the entire file after the `cppcode` region `C++` highlighted

Comment: I had similar problem with perl regions, it could be an error/incompatibility in the embedded (or embedding?) language's syntax file.  To check you might want to use the sample code under `:h synid` to get or `:h synstack` to get name of syntax elements under cursor to confirm that your defined region is in fact ending at your end marker. If it is then it confirms an incompatibility in the syntax file.